# Cloud9 IDE: debug c++ application

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, cloud9-ide

tried to run simple c++ applciation in Cloud9  online IDE.
I'm newbie in remote gdb debugging ("remote - I don't mean real remote debug, but a using client/server debug , as I see there is actually local debugging but, anyway , I see runner configuration that uses gdbserver and gdb on the same host).
I'm using c++ runner provided on the community forum, which has an only difference from default c++ runner that builds using makefile instead of direct g++ compilation. here it is:

```
{
  "script": [
    "set -e",
    "cd /home/ubuntu/workspace/build",
    "make",
    "chmod 755 \"my_app\"",
    "if [ \"$debug\" == true ]; then ",
      "gdbserver --once :15470 \"my_app\" $args",
    "else",
      "my_app $args",
    "fi"
  ],
  "info": "Running Project",
  "debugport": 15470,
  "debugger": "gdb",
  "executable": "my",
  "maxdepth": 50,
  "$debugDefaultState": false,
  "env": {},
  "selector": "^.*\\.(cpp|cc)$"
}
```

when I'm running this with enabled debug, I see this output:

```
Running Project                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
....
[100%] Built target my_app                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Process my_app created; pid = 25969                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Listening on port 15470                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Remote debugging from host 127.0.0.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
My Test Application                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        description of my test applciation                                                                                                                                                                                                       
usage:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
         my_app [task_name] [task_parameters ...]                                                                                                                                                                                              

Child exited with status 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
GDBserver exiting
```

so this is a default run of the app without parameters , which only shows a description .
however it doesn't stop on any breakpoint. this is a primary issue and my question here

From the output above , for me, it is unclear - is gdb successfully connected to gdbserver or not? 
so the problem is in the connection between gdbserver and gdb ? 
or in IDE which didn't stop on the breakpoint?
(I've set the breakpoints in a lot of places, including before/after description output and at start/end of main function)

Comment: Since your makefile isn't shown. Is the app built with debug symbols enabled?

Comment: makefile has been generated by cmake with -DCMAKE_Build_Type = Debug

Comment: you were right , need to investigate makefile, which was generated by cmake, default c++ template works fine, with a debug tracing

Comment: do I understand C9 right - there are two configuration files - builder and runner, so right way is a runner should contain a running command only, not a make. Make/cmake/build/g++/etc should be in a builder file. correct?

Comment: You could use that, but I think using the runner to build then run everything would be good too.

Comment: that's oddly, simple c++ project with one cpp file (30 lines) and 8 headers (<100 lines per file) could not be compiled in C9 due the hit of memory limit. seems free version does fit for hello world only. I suppose that gcc has some flags to reduce memory usage at compilation time, and tried a few ones but with no success. I've contacted with your sales to provide me with paid plan with RAM 1Gb only without other premium features and not so expensive like $20 per month. but also - no deal :( . looking for alternatives for cloud development...

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments, the problem was resolved by adding gcc flags to add debug info into the build, I mean

> "/usr/bin/g++ -ggdb3

actually I was using C9 for a build and debug c++ project based on cmake .
so it works , no problem but requires some effort to tune builders and runners.
against each  target in cmake manually. it's not so useful, but can be used